# Why JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ignoring JsonPropertyName attributes?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have problem with JsonConvert deserializer. I have class

```
[BsonCollection("matches")]
public class MatchData : Document
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string ExternalMatchId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

In my controller, I am trying to deserialize in this way:

```
[HttpPost("end")]
public ActionResult RoundEnd([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    var saveData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MatchData>(data.ToString());

    ...
}
```

Input JSON looks like

```
 "{"id": "61696f268c7b70b5f3e85803",
 "game_server_id": "615ed4a1cd95e8209a4ab67d",
...
```

But in my output `MatchData` object `ExternalMatchId` is null. How to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure about `BsonCollectionAttribute`?

Comment: I've tried without it, the same output.

Comment: Has your `Document ` class a property `id`?

Comment: What does `data.ToString()` give? I have a feeling it's probably not what you expect

Comment: I think you have mixed System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft. Please try to use `JsonProperty` attribute on `ExternalMatchId` or use the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MatchData>` method in your controller action.

Answer (score 9):

You are mixing frameworks here. The `JsonPropertyName` attribute is for the `System.Text.Json` namespace whereas you are using JSON.Net to deserialise. So the solution is to stick with one of them. Either deserialise with the built in framework:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MatchData>(data.ToString());
```

Or switch the attributes to use the JSON.Net versions:

```
[JsonProperty("Foo")]
```

Having said all that, it looks like you can simplify the whole thing by getting MVC to do the work for you. Instead of using `dynamic` as the model (don't do that - dynamic is problematic and every time you use it a kitten dies), put the model in here directly:

```
public ActionResult RoundEnd([FromBody] MatchData data)
```

Comment: Putting MatchData to action args, should I stick with ```[JsonProperty("id")]``` attribute?

Comment: No, `JsonPropertyName` will be fine unless you have done something like `services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();` in your startup.

Comment: I don't have AddMvc() in my startup. Can I still use  .AddNewtonsoftJson() somehow?

Comment: You don't need to add it.

Comment: After put [FromBody] MatchData now i am not getting to controller action. HTTP Requests                                                                                                           -------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   POST /v1/webhook/round-end     500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I'd need to know more about the error to understand why that happens.

Comment: I can't even tell more because, I am getting this as POST webhook. Is it possible to determine something before 500 internal server error happens? Maybe some breakpoint.

Comment: Then debug it locally and post into your webhook using something like Postman. I'm sorry, I can't help more than that.

Comment: I've got it working with AddNewtonsoftJson() in Startup and [JsonProperty("id")] attribute. I think I should try to figure out with System.Text.Json without adding Mvc.NewtonSoft dependency.

Comment: Using System.Json deserializer, I am getting an error: " System.InvalidOperationException: The JSON property name for 'Application.Common.Dependencies.DataAccess.Entity.MatchData.Id' collides with another property." . That can be because I have ```ObjectId Id``` property in my Document abstract class and IDocument interface. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I've fixed it setting ```[JsonPropertyName("_id")]``` for ```ObjectId Id``` property