# ASP.Net Web API, Why are my JSONs full of weird data and not formatting?

Tags: c#, json, http, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a class Company that looks like this.

```
public class Company
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("companyID")]
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("vehicleIDs")]
        public List<string> VehicleIDs { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("companyName")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my first time making an API, also first time working with C#. I am creating a List and trying to return it as a Json from my GET method. However, anyway that I have tried to do so seems to result in a ton of information I have no clue where it's coming from being there. I have also tried formatting so that it appears indented and this also does not seem to be working.

Currently my GET method is just returning a List, and in my WebApiConfig.cs Register method I have

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

This is working to a degree, and i'm at least able to use and access my list of objects I receive, but the Json looks like this

```
[{"$id":"1","CompanyID":"28","VehicleIDs":["1900","2121","1802","2125","1701","1703","1702"],"Email":"ElizabethHarper","CompanyName":"Allegany Paratransit","Configuration":null,"ControllerContext":{"$id":"2","Configuration":null,"ControllerDescriptor":null,"Controller":null,"Request":null,"RequestContext":{"$id":"3","Request":null,"ClientCertificate":null,"Configuration":null,"IncludeErrorDetail":false,"IsLocal":false,"RouteData":null,"Url":null,"VirtualPathRoot":null,"Principal":{"$id":"4","m_identity":{"$id":"5","System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.version":"1.0","System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.nameClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name","System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.roleClaimType":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid","System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.claims":"AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAAAI4BU3lzdGVtLkNvbGxlY3Rpb25zLkdlbmVyaWMuTGlzdGAxW1tTeXN0ZW0uU2VjdXJpdHkuQ2xhaW1zLkNsYWltLCBtc2NvcmxpYiwgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPWI3N2E1YzU2MTkzNGUwODldXQMAAAAGX2l0ZW1zBV9zaXplCF92ZXJzaW9uAwAAHlN5c3RlbS5TZWN1cml0eS5DbGFpbXMuQ2xhaW1bXQgICQIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcCAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAxxTeXN0ZW0uU2VjdXJpdHkuQ2xhaW1zLkNsYWltCw==","m_userToken":{"$id":"6","value":0}},"m_roles":null,"m_rolesTable":null,"m_rolesLoaded":false,"m_version":"1.0","m_serializedClaimsIdentities":"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"}},"RouteData":null},"ActionContext":{"$id":"7","ControllerContext":{"$ref":"2"},"ActionDescriptor":null,"ModelState":{},"ActionArguments":{},"Response":null,"Request":null,"RequestContext":{"$ref":"3"}},"ModelState":{},"Request":null,"RequestContext":{"$ref":"3"},"Url":null,"User":{"$ref":"4"}},{"$id":"8","CompanyID":"27","VehicleIDs":["312","311","2105"],"Email":"erobison-harper@alleganygov.org","CompanyName":"Allegany Fixed Bus","Configuration":null,"ControllerContext":{"$id":"9","Configuration":null,"ControllerDescriptor":null,"Controller":null,"Request":null,"RequestContext":{"$id":"10","Request":null,"ClientCertificate":null,"Configuration":null,"IncludeErrorDetail":false,"IsLocal":false,"RouteData":null,"Url":null,"VirtualPathRoot":null,"Principal":{"$ref":"4"}},"RouteData":null},"ActionContext":{"$id":"11","ControllerContext":{"$ref":"9"},"ActionDescriptor":null,"ModelState":{},"ActionArguments":{},"Response":null,"Request":null,"RequestContext":{"$ref":"10"}},"ModelState":{},"Request":null,"RequestContext":{"$ref":"10"},"Url":null,"User":{"$ref":"4"}}]
```

I have no idea where or what this extra text is coming from. I have tried returning it as a Json string using both Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json, both seem to produce similar results.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: "Currently my GET method is just returning a List," Can you post your get method pls?

Comment: It's fairly long, most of it is me calling other methods to query the database and evaluate the data. What I am returning is a List<Company>.

Comment: Show at least the action header and the last several lines. And it would be nice to see the code that you use to get this json from response

Comment: You said `This is my first time making an API, also first time working with C#`, if it's your first time you should not rush for complex stuffs. write a simple method return `List<Company>` even with dummy data, see the result, if it wasn't desired. post your question. Incrementally add more codes to get close to the complex method if everything is going well or you find an issue.

Comment: @RezaNoei I'm not new to programming in the slightest and this is for my own knowledge. I have done exactly what you're describing already. I started by returning List<string[]> when I began this. I then did not like how it worked on the other end and moved to make the Company class, and now here I am.

Comment: @Serge Forgive my ignorance, what action header?

Comment: Your API header with input and output

Comment: The attribute `[JsonPropertyName]` is for the System.Text.Json serializer, but `SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` is for the Json.NET serializer.  If you are actually using Json.NET then `[JsonPropertyName("companyID")]` will have no effect, and you must use `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("companyID")]`.   See [Why JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ignoring JsonPropertyName attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69584498).  Can you confirm which serializer you are using?

Comment: *Currently my GET method is just returning a List* -- in order to help you, we are going to need to see a [mcve] showing code that reproduces the problem.  If you can reproduce the problem returning dummy data, that would be ideal.  See [ask].

Comment: Is there any chance that your `public class Company` is actually a `public partial class Company` and that some additional fields and properties are defined in some other `public partial` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. I'm not quite sure when this happened, may have been the result of intellisense, I don't know.

This:

```
public class Company
{
    [JsonPropertyName("companyID")]
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("vehicleIDs")]
    public List<string> VehicleIDs { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("companyName")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Became:

```
public class Company : ApiController
{
    [JsonPropertyName("companyID")]
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("vehicleIDs")]
    public List<string> VehicleIDs { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("companyName")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Removing : ApiController has resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It appears as though it is returning some sort of httpresponse within each Company entity. I don't know how you managed to do this; I haven't seen anything like that before. I notice that the attributes seem to have no effect -- the property names in the returned json are Pascal case rather than the casing you assigned in JsonPropertyName.

I have a different approach that has always worked for me where the attributed json property names will be converted.

If you are willing to use Newtonsoft.Json, attribute the properties in your Company entity with Newtonsoft's JsonProperty instead of JsonPropertyName, and you can convert each Company object to a JObject and add them all to a JArray before returning them in a response. Something like this in your controller:

```
JArray ja = new JArray();
foreach (Company company in context.Companies.ToArray())
{
    JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(company);
    ja.Add(jo);
}
JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.None,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
return new JsonResult(ja, jsonSettings);
```

Comment: I think you're right in the regard of the httpresponse within each entity. I have no idea as to how it's happening, I have researched quite a bit. I just tried your method, and somehow the issue gets worse. There is so much text wrapped in there.

Comment: The downvote certainly didn't come from me. I fixed the issue, I posted an answer above.

Answer (score -3):

you can Try to to provide return type as json
Like we have actionresult Task just reomve and make method to return Json.
like public jsonresult

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).